# PlatformIO - Creating a library including a 3rd party library

Tags: library, platformio

I'm using PlatformIO, and I'm trying to create a library who uses another library in it.

(1) For that I created an empty library called `ABCD.h` stored in a `newrep` github repository.

(2) 3rd party library chosen is `Panda_segmentBed_I2C.h` with no particular reason.

(3) That library was inserted as needed to `lib_deps` and initiate `build` update the newly create library that it pulled 3rd party library as needed, as shown in pic1 [image]

(4) `ABCD.h` includes `#include <Panda_segmentBed_I2C.h>`

(5) Now to simulate a use of `ABCD.h` library inside a code, I've created a new project called `TEST_NEWREP`. Only 1 line was added to project:  `#include <ABCD.h>`

(6) After running `build` I get an error that 3rd party library, inside `ABCD.h` is not found.

(7) see `TEST_NEWREP` tree:

[image]

**Edit 1 - update `.gitignore` **

Somehow, when Project is created, a default `.gitignore` includes an ignore of `.pio` library. Perhaps in some cases it should be ignored, but when that Project is a library, it does not upload `.pio\libdeps`. Now after the exclude is removed, all dependencies are pulled as needed when `build` the project, BUT STILL ERROR REMAINS THAT `Panda_segmentBed_I2C.h` is not found.

Comment: You `main.cpp` should be in the same source directory with `ABCD.h` and `ABCD.cpp` (as a local library), and you declare it as `#include "ABCD.h"` in your `main.cpp`.

Comment: @hcheung but `main.cpp` is not part of library files.

Comment: You don't need to mess with the `.gitignore`, when compiling the code, the platformIO will download the library based on your `libdeps` configuration in your platformio.ini file.

Comment: If `ABCD.h` is a separate library, then you only need to set up the `libdeps` in your platformio.ini to use it. From the first picture you shown, the `ABCD.h` is not an independent library, but a local file to the project `newrep`.